# Does DataGrid on CE 5.0 Compact Framework .NET support editing?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am trying to get a DataGrid under CE 5.0 / .NET CF 2.0 that a user can edit.  The document at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838165.aspx indicates that some environments do not support editing -

> As there is no native support for
>   editing in the DataGrid control, this
>   needs to be implemented manually

Do I need to implement this ugly example - which doesn't work very well as shown?

The documentation is not clear about which .NET features are available on which platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not directly editable.  MSDN has samples for using the DataGrid, including suggestions for data editing, for both [Pocket PC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229684.aspx) and [Smartphone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229659.aspx) devices.  Either one would be a reasonable start for a generic CE device, but the general strategy is to determine which cell is active and place a textbox over it for editing capability.

You might also look at [Eric Hartwell's extensions for the DataGrid](http://www.ehartwell.com/InfoDabble/DataGrid_extensions_for_the_Compact_Framework) as well as the [CF datagrid on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/DotNetCompactGC.aspx).

Of course the usual suspects like Resco and ComponentOne also have commercial offerings.

Comment: Does anyone know if they're planning to put one in for future versions of CF?

Comment: They have no plans to do so that I'm aware of (and I'm pretty close to them).  I think their typical MO is to let the market develop one.  The frustrating thing is that the control is written in pure C# - I wish they'd just publish the source for the damned thing and let us make it what it should be

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DataGrid does not support editing. What I do, is use it for displaying read only data and then provide a separate form for editing the selected record.

If you must support editing in a grid layout, then I would look for a third party component.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838165.aspx

Guys it can be done..Just follow it..Its so simple when its done ;P..

Answer (score 1):

The link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838165.aspx was really helpful but I think that there is a bug. 
Instead of

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)grdOrders.DataSource;
DataView dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

It should be

```
DataView dataView = (DataView)itemdataentryGrid.DataSource;
DataTable dataTable = dataView.Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aye, in my opinion its a joke. God knows why they've left it like this since 1.0.
On my first ever CF project I assumed it was available and spent an age implementing a read-write one cause i'd put it in the agreed spec.... :(

I learnt a very important lesson that day : Don't expect anything from the FF to be in CF (or rather, check before quoting!).